# El componente calendar de primefaces no muestra el calendario

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tal como indica el titulo, estoy desarrollando una aplicación web con Primefaces en la que utilizo el componente calendar. En la mayor parte de los casos el componente funciona correctamente, sin embargo, en algunos casos el componente no muestra el calendario. En su lugar, se muestra como si fuese un simple campo de texto con autocompletar (ver imagen).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de dicho componente es el siguiente:

```
<p:dialog
            header="Generar Paro"
            id="dlgGenerarParo"
            closable="false" closeOnEscape="false"
            width="820" modal="true"
            widgetVar="dlgGenerarParo">

        <p:layout style="width: 810px; height: 420px;">

            <p:layoutUnit position="center">
                <p:panelGrid style="border: 0;height:150px;" columns="2" rendered="true">


                    <h:outputText value="Estado:"/>
                    <h:outputText
                            id="txtEstadoParo"
                            style="font-weight: bold;"
                            value="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.generarParoBean.arbolEstadosBean.estadoSeleccionadoDescripcion}"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Fecha inicio paro:"/>
                    <p:calendar locale="es"
                                id="calFInicioParo"
                                showOn="button"
                                widgetVar="calFInicioParo"
                                value="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.generarParoBean.fechaInicioParo}"
                                pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"/>

                    <h:outputText value="Fecha fin paro:"/>
                    <p:calendar locale="es"
                                id="calFFinParo"
                                showOn="button"
                                widgetVar="calFFinParo"
                                value="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.generarParoBean.fechaFinParo}"
                                pattern="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"/>
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:layoutUnit>

            <p:layoutUnit style="border: 0;" size="100" position="south">

                <p:messages closable="true" autoUpdate="true" for="generarParoMessages" showDetail="true"
                            showSummary="false"/>
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="text-align: center; width: 50%; border: 0;">
                    <p:commandButton
                            value="Aceptar"
                            actionListener="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.confirmarGenerarParo}"/>
                    <p:commandButton
                            value="Cancelar"
                            actionListener="#{monitorizadorCentroControlador.cancelarGenerarParo}"/>
                </p:panelGrid>

            </p:layoutUnit>
        </p:layout>

    </p:dialog>
```

La única diferencia notable con respecto a los controles calendario que funcionan correctamente, es que estoy utilizando el control en un diálogo, lo cual es posible que esté influyendo en su funcionamiento.

Comment: Me parece que el tema se da por el campo `pattern`. No lo he probado, pero intenta quitándolo.

Comment: He probado, sin embargo el control sigue comportandose del mismo modo.

Comment: ¿en la consola del navegador no se aprecia ningún error?

Answer (score 2):

intenta con esta estructura:

```
 <p:calendar value="#{bean.fecha}" id="fecha"
        navigator="true" showOn="button" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" locale="es"
        converterMessage="tu mensaje" yearRange="c-120:c" mindate="01/01/1900"                               
        size="25" styleClass="tuStilo">
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="tuValidacion"
            update="@form" process="@this"/>                       
        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
 </p:calendar>
```

Comment: He probado pero tampoco funciona. Sigo pensando que tiene algo que ver con incrustar el control en un diálogo, sin embargo no estoy seguro al 100%.

Answer (score 1):

remueve el showOn del calendar, si quieres que este salga cuando le hagan focus de lo contrario saldría cuando le den click al botón de la derecha

Comment: Creo que no me he explicado del todo bien. El problema es que cuando haces click en el botón primefaces no renderiza el calendario. En el caso en el que, como dices, elimino el showOn del calendar, cuando el control obtiene el foco tampoco muestra el calendario.

Comment: has revisado la consola javascript ??

Comment: Si, no aparece ningún error.

Answer (score 0):

Si en algunos casos el componente funciona bien y en otros no, eso significa que algo está impidiendo el correcto funcionamiento bajo unas condiciones especificas.
Creo que el problema está en el javascript o css que ocupa primefaces para desplegar el calendario. El conflicto sería que estás agregando algún otro scrypt o css que se sobrepone y genera el problema, prueba desactivando los scrypt o css adicionales y si vuelve a funcionar ya sabes donde está el problema.